# Django + uWSGI + Nginx + SSL - request for working configuration (emphasis on SSL)

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, uwsgi

Does anyone have a working configuration for these four?

```
- Django
- uWSGI
- Nginx
- SSL
```

The main question is how to correctly set up `SSL` for this?  I've googled a lot, and still can't get it to work.  I have a working set up for `http` with `unix sockets`, but that's as far as I could get.

There are some other answers posted, but they are mostly code snippets, and not a whole configuration.

Comment: it's common to have ssl terminate at nginx, then nginx talks to the upstream servers (uWSGI) through http.  There are many many examples of this online, one of which is https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination

Comment: @dm03514 I understand that `https` will terminate at the public facing `nginx reverse proxy server`.  The tutorial link is helpful.  Do the `location / ... proxy ` args block apply to `uWSGI` are those need to be replaced with `uwsgi` arguments?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*)  https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     example.com;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log combined;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log error;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/example-unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    location /static/ {
        alias /webapps/example/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /webapps/example/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

This is basic nginx configuration that will work with SSL and will forward requests to uwsgi running on port 8000 (you can change this to socket if you want).

For advanced SSL settings check [THIS](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/).

Comment: I cannot get this to work.  Have you done this set up before for `uwsgi + nginx + django + ssl`?? If so, could you provide an example `uwsgi.ini` file?  Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In our company we use uwsgi for running Django, but sadly I can't share template here. I can just tell you that nginx template is almost identical to this one (this is my personal one). There is no difference regarding uwsgi if you are using https or not, so problem should be somewhere else. I personally prefer Gunicorn for running Django (in our company we use uwsgi only because latest versions support web sockets). Do you have any reason for using uwsgi? I can give you template for running Gunicorn if you want.

Comment: Yea, I need to use `uwsgi` to work with web sockets for my current project. I have used Gunicorn in the past and have a working version with it.  Thank you for your help, I hope to solve this in the next day or so.

Comment: your configuration is exactly correct.  I had not opened up port `443/tcp` for `ssl`, so it was the `ufw` that was blocking the request.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Great that you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to nginx,uwsgi and ssl. Here shares my testing nginx and uwsgi config.

Basically, there are four steps to deploy Django only support SSL/HTTPS.

1. Setup a SSL Certificate

   - use openssl to generate server.crt and server.key

     > openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key
2. Config nginx.conf and uwsgi.ini under Django project

   - Set nginx.conf (sorry,the layout is weird in text block, so I insert a picture here.)
     [image]
   - symlink to this file from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled so nginx can see it

     > sudo ln -s /path/to/django/example_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   - config uwsgi.ini under django project
     [image]
3. Config settings.py

   ```
   SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
   SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
   SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
   ```
4. Restart nginx and uwsgi

   - restart nginx

     > sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
   - run uwsgi

     > uwsgi --ini /path/to/django/example_uwsgi.ini